# Constructing an oscillating function with minima and saddles above 0

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking for an oscillating function with minima and saddles above $0$. Any such function will do; I don't need it in any specific form.

How should I go about constructing such a function? The "oscillating" part immediately suggests a trigonometric function of some kind, but it seems very hard to get a $y = \sin{A x} + \cos{B x}$ function to yield saddles. I can get minima with $y > 0$, but haven't found a solution for saddles.

Comment: Can you precise the domain and codomain of your expected map? A saddle point is not defined for $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can define $f$ as a piecewise function. For example, you can set
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
\sin^2(x)+2 & x \in [2k\pi, (2k+1)\pi],\\
\cos^2(x)+1 & x \in [(2k+1)\pi,(2k+2)\pi],
\end{cases}
$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If you plot these functions separately, you see that $f$ should satisfy the properties you need.